# Prolog A* greedy search operator expected

Tags: prolog, greedy

Been trying to find the next node using heuristic value after each iteration for a while now - I think it's nearly there but I'm getting an error.

```
greedy_search(GoalNode,_,0) :-
    goal(GoalNode).

greedy_search(CurrentNode,GoalNode,TotalCost) :-
    connected(CurrentNode,NextNode,D),
    write('Exploring '),
    write(CurrentNode),nl,
    write(HCost(N,V)),nl,
    find(NextNode,GoalNode,NextCost),
    write('Visited '),
    write(NextNode),nl,
    write(HCost(N,V)),
    TotalCost is  NextCost + D.
```

Error is Syntax error: Operator expected

I would like to print the next node at each iteration using the greedy search and also the total cost at the end.

I have a set of connections on the arc like so (a,b,2). and also a heuristic table, represented like so: h(b,4).

Comment: `HCost` should be `'HCost'` to be a valid atom.

Comment: @gusbro I have h(b,4) above so = HCost(N,V).?

Comment: what I'm saying is that `HCost` (which starts with an upper case letter) is a variable but you want to use a term `'HCost'(N,V)`.

Comment: Get it now. Although it's not giving me the correct answer. Thanks tho!

Comment: Are you trying to call `'HCost'(N,V)` as a function? Because Prolog doesn't evaluate like that.

Comment: @DanielLyons I was but have sinced rectified that. It's now just HCost.